# Can we track sniffers in a network?

Tags: sniffer

It is very simple to launch Wireshark in monitor mode and listen to connections in the host network.

I have come across a program called [SniffDet](http://www.securiteam.com/tools/6G00S006AQ.html). Is it an all round solution for finding sniffers on a network or is there a better program/way to do it which I am missing out?

Comment: What are you attempting to find? Other people running Wireshark to look at the local traffic?

Comment: Yes right @Matthew

Answer (score 3):

NMAP has a [sniffer-detect script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/sniffer-detect.html) built-into it, it's probably the most simple solution out there. I have seen no comparison of the two tools on their effectiveness.

Note that all these solutions do is try and find interfaces running promiscuous mode, there are many ways to sniff a network which would leave no traces at all, for instance taps and spans.